# Jsp Alert If else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

For the following I want to run a script to see if a string is equal to another when a button is clicked.

```
<wts:input label="Chemical Name TODO" inputId="synName" path="chemicalName" maxLength="100" size="100"></wts:input>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
                   <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="unknownAlert()" />
                   <c:if test="${techView}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="techView" value="${techView}">
                    </c:if> 
                   <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="resetButton" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>


<script>
function unknownAlert() {
    if($('#synName') == 'Unknown'){
        alert("Unknown Working");
    }
}
</script>
```

When the user types in the string, Unknown or unknown, once the search button is clicked that it runs the script to know if to alert. Stuck currently on how to check the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
 if($('#synName').val() === 'Unknown')
```

You want to compare against the value of your input, not the input itself (that's just a jQuery DOM object).

Additionally if you want it to be case insensitive you can just use the `toLower()` function before you compare:

```
 if($('#synName').val().toLower() === 'unknown')
```

Comment: no problem! accepting the answer would be greatly appreciated :)